# Determine through program whether blackberry device is unlocked

Tags: blackberry, status, unlock

Please let us know if there is a way to find out whether Blackberry Device is unlocked (Can be used on any network) or locked (Tied to particular Network) through RIM APIs.

Thanks,
Mahim.

Answer (score 0):

I hope the deviceInfo class of the rim api must be having a method which could return us whether a device is in holster or not and also i think it returns for how much time the device is idle

Better check that class.It will be helpful